# RDLC line chart with auto-scaling Y-Axis, but strictly positive numbers only

Tags: .net, charts, rdlc, autoscaling

I am using an RDLC line chart much the way [as described here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Line-Chart-in-RDLC-Report-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx). This works fine so far.

**My data is strictly positive** and I want to use the auto-scaling feature of the chart. I have set the "Vertical Axis Properties" to Minimum:Auto and Maximum:Auto, and did NOT check the "Always include zero". My data is usually single-digit numbers, but occasionally also zero.

This is how it looks like:

[image: 2 Example charts with different data]

Now, in the left chart the data is all zero, and I would like the chart to omit the negative axis part.

**How to define an autoscaling Y-Axis and strictly omit negative parts in the axis?** Will I need to use the function type for the limits?

Update: I have tried to use a function expression for the Minimum value:

```
=Max(0, "Auto")
```

But this did not change anything visibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try always setting the **minimum value of the axis** to the actual minimum value of your data?

```
=Min(Fields!MyField1.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Or if you have multiple datasets or fields that would need comparing:

```
=IIF(Min(Fields!MyField1.Value, "DataSet1") > Min(Fields!MyField2.Value, "DataSet2"), Min(Fields!MyField2.Value, "DataSet2"), Min(Fields!MyField1.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

If the above doesn't seem possible with your data, then perhaps the `Margin` property might be of use to you. If you put this on *False* the first chart shouldn't go below zero.

[image: Chart Axis Margin]